# "for" vs "each" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, foreach, iteration, each

I just had a quick question regarding loops in Ruby. Is there a difference between these two ways of iterating through a collection?

```
# way 1
@collection.each do |item|
  # do whatever
end

# way 2
for item in @collection
  # do whatever
end
```

Just wondering if these are exactly the same or if maybe there's a subtle difference (possibly when `@collection` is nil).

Answer (score 340, accepted):

This is the only difference:

**each:**

```
irb> [1,2,3].each { |x| }
  => [1, 2, 3]
irb> x
NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from :0
```

**for:**

```
irb> for x in [1,2,3]; end
  => [1, 2, 3]
irb> x
  => 3
```

With the `for` loop, the iterator variable still lives after the block is done. With the `each` loop, it doesn't, unless it was already defined as a local variable before the loop started.

Other than that, `for` is just syntax sugar for the `each` method.

When `@collection` is `nil` both loops throw an exception:

> Exception: undefined local variable or method `@collection' for main:Object

Comment: is there a good reason why x remains in the for case or is this bad design :P? Seems to me this is rather unintuitive comparing with most other languages.

Comment: @cyc115 The reason why `x` remains in the *for* scenario is due to the fact that (generally speaking) keywords don't create new scopes. *if*, *unless*, *begin*, *for*, *while*, etc. all work with the current scope. `#each` however accepts a block. Blocks always add their own scope on top of the current scope. Meaning that declaring a new variable in the block (thus a new scope) will not be accessible from outside the block since that additional scope is not available there.

Comment: So does it mean `each` is a better option since it release the iterator from memory after the loop.

Comment: @ChuckZHB: The iterator is released (assuming no other references). It's only the last *value* it produced that might stick around. Whether that's a good or bad thing depends on what you want (sometimes it's useful to have the final value after the loop).

Answer (score 52):

See "[The Evils of the For Loop](http://graysoftinc.com/early-steps/the-evils-of-the-for-loop)" for a good explanation (there's one small difference considering variable scoping).

Using `each` is [considered more idiomatic](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops) use of Ruby.

Comment: @zachlatta: Thanks for notifying. I'll edit the link to point to a webarchive.org variant of the article!

Comment: http://graysoftinc.com/early-steps/the-evils-of-the-for-loop is the new link, now that JEG2's site is back online.

Answer (score 36):

Your first example,

```
@collection.each do |item|
  # do whatever
end
```

[is more idiomatic](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops). While Ruby supports looping constructs like `for` and `while`, the block syntax is generally preferred.

Another subtle difference is that any variable you declare within a `for` loop will be available outside the loop, whereas those within an iterator block are effectively private.

Comment: `while` and `until` do actually have some very concrete uses that cannot be replaced with each such as for example generating unique values or for REPL's.

Answer (score 7):

One more difference:

```
number = ["one", "two", "three"]
 => ["one", "two", "three"] 

loop1 = []
loop2 = []

number.each do |c|
  loop1 << Proc.new { puts c }
end
 => ["one", "two", "three"] 

for c in number
  loop2 << Proc.new { puts c }
end
 => ["one", "two", "three"] 

loop1[1].call
two
 => nil 

loop2[1].call
three
 => nil
```

source: http://paulphilippov.com/articles/enumerable-each-vs-for-loops-in-ruby

for more clear: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/179264#784884

Answer (score 7):

Never ever use `for` it may cause almost untraceable bugs.

Don't be fooled, this is not about idiomatic code or style issues. Ruby's implementation of `for` has a serious flaw and should not be used.

Here is an example where `for` introduces a bug,

```
class Library
  def initialize
    @ary = []
  end
  def method_with_block(&block)
    @ary << block
  end
  def method_that_uses_these_blocks
    @ary.map(&:call)
  end
end

lib = Library.new

for n in %w{foo bar quz}
  lib.method_with_block { n }
end

puts lib.method_that_uses_these_blocks
```

Prints

```
quz
quz
quz
```

Using `%w{foo bar quz}.each { |n| ... }` prints

```
foo
bar
quz
```

Why?

In a `for` loop the variable `n` is defined once and only and then that one definition is use for all iterations. Hence each blocks refer to the same `n` which has a value of `quz` by the time the loop ends. Bug!

In an `each` loop a fresh variable `n` is defined for each iteration, for example above the variable `n` is defined three separate times. Hence each block refer to a separate `n` with the correct values.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no difference, `for` uses `each` underneath.

```
$ irb
>> for x in nil
>> puts x
>> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):1
>> nil.each {|x| puts x}
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4
```

Like Bayard says, each is more idiomatic. It hides more from you and doesn't require special language features.
**Per Telemachus's Comment**

`for ..  in ..` sets the iterator outside the scope of the loop, so

```
for a in [1,2]
  puts a
end
```

leaves `a` defined after the loop is finished. Where as `each` doesn't. Which is another reason in favor of using `each`, because the temp variable lives a shorter period.

Comment: There _is_ a small difference (as yjerem, ChristopheD and Bayard mention) concerning variable scope.

Comment: Incorrect, `for` does not use `each` underneath. See other answers.

Comment: @akuhn For further clarification please see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39839809/5101493) and both its excellent answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1..4).each { |i| 


  a = 9 if i==3

  puts a 


}
#nil
#nil
#9
#nil

for i in 1..4

  a = 9 if i==3

  puts a

end
#nil
#nil
#9
#9
```

In 'for' loop, local variable is still lives after each loop. In 'each' loop, local variable refreshes after each loop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using blocks instead of in-language control structures is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make a specific point about the for in loop in Ruby. It might seem like a construct similar to other languages, but in fact it is an expression like every other looping construct in Ruby. In fact, the for in works with Enumerable objects just as the each iterator.

The collection passed to for in can be any object that has an each iterator method. Arrays and hashes define the each method, and many other Ruby objects do, too. The for/in loop calls the each method of the specified object. As that iterator yields values, the for loop assigns each value (or each set of values) to the specified variable (or variables) and then executes the code in body.

This is a silly example, but illustrates the point that the for in loop works with ANY object that has an each method, just like how the each iterator does:

```
class Apple
  TYPES = %w(red green yellow)
  def each
    yield TYPES.pop until TYPES.empty?
  end
end

a = Apple.new
for i in a do
  puts i
end
yellow
green
red
=> nil
```

And now the each iterator:

```
a = Apple.new
a.each do |i|
  puts i
end
yellow
green
red
=> nil
```

As you can see, both are responding to the each method which yields values back to the block. As everyone here stated, it is definitely preferable to use the each iterator over the for in loop. I just wanted to drive home the point that there is nothing magical about the for in loop. It is an expression that invokes the each method of a collection and then passes it to its block of code. Hence, it is a very rare case you would need to use for in. Use the each iterator almost always (with the added benefit of block scope).

Answer (score 0):

## This is very important when using Ruby's `async`.

```
require 'async'

Async do
  for i in 5.times do
    Async do
      sleep(1)
      print(i.to_s + " ")
    end
  end
end
```

Will return: `4 4 4 4 4`  as `i` is not re-defined for every iteration.

```
require 'async'

Async do
  5.times.each do |i|
    Async do
      sleep(1)
      print(i.to_s + " ")
    end
  end
end
```

Will return: `0 1 2 3 4`  as `i` only ever lives inside the scope of its iteration's block.

The reason for this becomes fairly obvious when reading the other answers, but since online searches for this kind of problem with `async` in the query don't return any results mentioning this I left this answer here.

**Do not use `for .. in ..` in conjunction with `async`!**