# Ruby: What is the difference between a for loop and an each loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, foreach, syntax, control-flow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [for vs each in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294509/for-vs-each-in-ruby)

Let's say that we have an array, like

`sites = %w[stackoverflow stackexchange serverfault]`

What's the difference between

```
for x in sites do
  puts x
end
```

and

```
sites.each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

?

They seem to do the same exact thing, to me, and the syntax of the `for` loop is clearer to me. Is there a difference? In what situations would this be a big deal?

Comment: I checked for something like that, but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a subtle difference regarding scoping, but I would recommend understanding it well as it reveals some of important aspects of Ruby.

`for` is a syntax construct, somewhat similar to `if`. Whatever you define in `for` block, will remain defined after `for` as well:

```
sites = %w[stackoverflow stackexchange serverfault]
#=> ["stackoverflow", "stackexchange", "serverfault"]

for x in sites do
  puts x
end
stackoverflow
stackexchange
serverfault
#=> ["stackoverflow", "stackexchange", "serverfault"]
x
#=> "serverfault"
```

On the other hand, `each` is a *method* which receives a block. Block introduces new lexical scope, so whatever variable you introduce in it, will not be there after the method finishes:

```
sites.each do |y|
  puts y
end
stackoverflow
stackexchange
serverfault
#=> ["stackoverflow", "stackexchange", "serverfault"]
y
NameError: undefined local variable or method `y' for #<Object:0x855f28 @hhh="hello">
    from (irb):9
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I would recommend forgetting about `for` completely, as using `each` is idiomatic in Ruby for traversing enumerables. It also recspects the paradigm of functional programming better, by decreasing chances of side-effects.

Comment: Great answer - very clear and thorough explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: Very interesting. I thought they are the same! :)

Comment: This came up in a technical interview, so good info!

Answer (score 8):

`sites.each` scopes `x` inside the block, whereas `for` will reuse `x` if declared outside the block.  In general it's better therefore to use `each`, it minimizes side effects over large bodies of code.

Answer (score 4):

CBZ answer is correct but incomplete since there is a difference in behavior between 1.8.X and 1.9.X:

1.9.2 IRB:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > x = [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > y = ["a","b"]
 => ["a", "b"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > x.each do |y|
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 >     p y
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005?>   end
1
2
3
4
5
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > y
 => ["a", "b"]
```

1.8.7 IRB:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > x = [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :002 > y = ["a","b"]
 => ["a", "b"] 
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :003 > x.each do |y|
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :004 >     p y
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :005?>   end
1
2
3
4
5
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :006 > y
 => 5
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. For what it's worth, I'm using 1.9.2.

Answer (score -1):

CBZ answer is correct.  To illustrate this, see this example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > a = %w{ blah lah kah }
 => ["blah", "lah", "kah"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > x = 1
 => 1 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > for x in a do
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 >     puts x
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005?>   end
blah
lah
kah
 => ["blah", "lah", "kah"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > x
 => "kah" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > x=1
 => 1 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > a.each do |x|
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 >     puts x
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010?>   end
blah
lah
kah
 => ["blah", "lah", "kah"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 > x
 => 1
```