# Splitting array and get desired elements

Tags: ruby

If I have this array:

`["1","2","3,a","4,b"]`

how can I get this array from it?

```
["1","2","3","4"].
```

Comment: Try something first, then we'll help you. If you don't want to spend time, why should we?

Comment: Great question Aurick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also works...

```
array=["1","2","3,a","4,b"]
  for i in 0..array.length()-1
    if array[i].include?(",")
      ab=array[i].split(",")
      array[i]=ab[0]
    end

  end
print array #["1","2","3","4"]
```

Comment: This works, but is almost as unRubylike as possible. I guess worse would be using .index instead of .include?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have all integers, (If not I guess you get the idea :))

```
["1","2","3,a","4,b"].collect {|i| i.to_i}
```

Comment: +1. The only answer to this point that actually looks like Ruby code.

Comment: `i.to_i.to_s` would be more exact, because author wants an array of strings, not an array of ints. But anyway, this code is much better then  the java code in the accepted answer.

Comment: Or just `.collect(&:to_i)`.

Answer (score 3):

With an array like:

```
ary = ["1","2","3,a","4,b"]
```

I'd use:

```
ary.map{ |s| s[/\A(\d+)/, 1] }
```

Which results in:

```
[
    [0] "1",
    [1] "2",
    [2] "3",
    [3] "4"
]
```

It simply finds the numerics at the start of the strings and returns them in a new array.

Comment: +1 wow, even more cleaner, (thats why I love ruby :))

Comment: Probably the best, but nothing in the sample input really implies that \A is necessary. Maybe just /\d+/

Comment: It's there to anchor for speed and to force accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
["1","2","3,a","4,b"].map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

to get array of strings

```
["1","2","3,a","4,b"].map(&:to_i).map(&:to_s)
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this delete option :

```
irb(main):014:0> a = ["101","2zd","3,a","10,ab"]
=> ["101", "2zd", "3,a", "10,ab"]
irb(main):015:0> count = a.count
irb(main):016:0> for i in 0..count 
irb(main):017:1> puts a[i].delete("^0-9")
irb(main):018:1> end
101
2
3
10
```

**UPDATED Code** ( Use of Each Loop - Thanks to the Tin Man)

```
irb(main):005:0>  a = ["101","2zd","3,a","10,ab"]
=> ["101", "2zd", "3,a", "10,ab"]
irb(main):006:0> b = []
=> []
irb(main):007:0> a.each do |t|
irb(main):008:1* b << t.delete("^0-9")
irb(main):009:1> end
=> ["101", "2zd", "3,a", "10,ab"]
irb(main):010:0> puts b
101
2
3
10
=> nil
```

Comment: `for` is not idiomatic in Ruby. Consider using `each` or `map` instead.

Comment: Thank a lot @theTinMan for your suggestion, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677081/ruby-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-an-each-loop

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5677251/128421 says the same thing.