# Is there any case to prefer for instead of each in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know that `for i in arr` slightly differs from `arr.each` scope and everyone keeps saying that iterators are preferrable, but I wonder if there is any case when cycle is preferrable and why it is (since iterators are more idiomatic)?

Comment: When prototyping in Ruby with intent to speed up with C extensions, I find it helps to use more C-like idioms, there is less to convert. But probably not the answer you are looking for . . .

Comment: This comment is not intended as an answer, merely giving some additional information. According this [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3294543/877472), both `for` and `each` use `.each` in the background. The main difference (according to [this answer from the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3294561/877472) ) is how the iterator variable is scoped. Ultimately, other than the Neil Slater's post, it sounds like there may not be any technical reason to prefer one over the other except.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- Use `for` loop for performance in Ruby 1.8
- Use `for` loop to standards in existing projects
- Use `each` loop to minimize side effects
- Prefer `each` loop.

**`each` minimizes side effects**

The primary difference between `for` and `each` is scoping.

The `each` function takes a block. Blocks create a new lexical scope. This means that any variables declared within the scope of the function will no longer be available after the function.

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  a = i
end

puts a
# => NameErrror: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

Whereas:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]
  a = i
end

puts a
# => 3
```

Thus, using the `each` syntax minimizes the risk of side effects.

**Determing exit point?**

This said, there are special instances where the `for` loop may be helpful. Specifically, when finding out where a loop exited.

```
for i in 1..3
  a = i

  break if i % 2 == 0
end

puts a
# => 0
```

There is a better way to do this though:

```
a = (1..3).each do |i|
  break i if i % 2 == 0
end
```

**Each is faster (in Ruby 2.0)**

```
Benchmark.bm(8) do |x|
  x.report "For" do
    max.times do
      for i in 1..100
        1 + 1
      end
    end
  end

  x.report "Each" do
    max.times do
      (1..100).each do |t|
        1+1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*Ruby 2.0*

```
               user     system      total        real
For        6.420000   0.000000   6.420000 (  6.419870)
Each       5.830000   0.000000   5.830000 (  5.829911)
```

*Ruby 1.8.6 (Slower Machine)*

```
              user     system      total        real
For      17.360000   0.000000  17.360000 ( 17.409992)
Each     21.130000   0.000000  21.130000 ( 21.250754)
```

**Benchmarks 2**

If you read the comment trail, there is a discussion about the speed of creating objects in `for` vs `each`. The [link provided](http://blog.shingara.fr/each-vs-for.html) had the following benchmarks (although, I have cleaned up the formatting and fixed the syntax errors).

```
b = 1..10e5

Benchmark.bmbm (10) do |x|
  x.report "each {}" do
    b.each { |r| r + 1 }
  end

  x.report "each do end" do
    b.each do |r|
      r + 1
    end
  end

  x.report "for do end" do
    for r in b do
      r + 1
    end
  end
end
```

*Ruby 2.0*

```
                  user     system      total        real
each {}       0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.144643)
each do end   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.143244)
for do end    0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.147112)
```

*Ruby 1.8.6*

```
                  user     system      total        real
each {}       0.840000   0.000000   0.840000 (  0.851634)
each do end   0.730000   0.000000   0.730000 (  0.732737)
for do end    0.650000   0.000000   0.650000 (  0.647186)
```

Comment: I understand this. I also know that internally Ruby converts for to each. But I wonder if there is still any case when for would be used instead of each.

Comment: I found that when performance is an issue the `for` loop can be beneficial. Creating objects in Ruby is expensive and can cause an performance hit in loop with many iterations.

Comment: @thomthom Can you provide benchmarks which show that this is the case?

Comment: @p0deje as explained in the answer it is only useful when you don't want the variable defined in the loop to be limited to the scope of the loop, which you can completely almost always avoid

Comment: @p0deje After thinking, I added an example of when it would be useful to use.

Comment: @screenmutt From this thread: http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=180&t=25305#p221022 referring to this link http://blog.shingara.fr/each-vs-for.html

Comment: Note that SketchUp has been using Ruby 1.8 and the performance results might be different in newer versions.

Comment: @thomthom I just added the benchmarks. It does look like Ruby 1.8 has a faster run time for `for` loops, but that has been fixed.

Comment: Ah - yea, that matches what I just tested as well. Things have been turned around.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a few plugins for SketchUp's Ruby API and I found that when iterating large collections (of geometry entities) I would get better performance with a `for in` loop over an `each` block.

I believe this to be because the `for in` loop doesn't create it's local scope and objects are reused instead of being created for every iteration as it would in the `each` loop.

---

EDIT: The speed gain depends on Ruby version. Using the test snippet used in this article http://blog.shingara.fr/each-vs-for.html:

**Ruby 1.8.6:**

```
              user     system      total        real
For      14.742000   0.000000  14.742000 ( 14.777000)
Each     18.190000   0.000000  18.190000 ( 18.194000)
```

**Ruby 2.0.0**

```
               user     system      total        real
For        5.975000   0.000000   5.975000 (  5.990000)
Each       5.444000   0.000000   5.444000 (  5.438000)
```

Things has greatly improved since the old 1.8.6. (Though, SketchUp extension developers still need to optimize against this version.)

Comment: 1.8.6 fell off supported status a long time ago. It was also a great deal slower, so its use for a comparison is dubious. Perhaps the final version of 1.8.7 would be more reasonable, but 1.9.3 would make more sense.

Comment: True, if you had control over the Ruby platform. But if you write extensions for SketchUp you have to deal with Ruby 1.8.6.