# Why is `for i in a` not idiomatic Ruby?

Tags: ruby, for-loop, coding-style, iterator

Ruby has support for the `for i in a` syntax, but no one really uses it. One of the design principles of Ruby is it's readability, and I find

```
for i in a
  ...
end
```

much more readable (and easier to type) than

```
a.each do |i|
  ...
end
```

Why is it not preferred? Do others not also find it more readable? Is it for consistency reasons, e.g., relation with other functions like `each_with_index` and variable scoping?

Comment: I think you should read about ruby blocks first. And this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294509/for-vs-each-in-ruby

Comment: The chances are that you find things more readable once you have trained yourself to read them. There doesn't seem any inherent superiority to either syntax to me. Other than that, it is mainly opinion, but the `.each` syntax falls into line more cleanly than `for` with other Ruby idioms. Take a look at the other iterators on `Array` and you will find not only that `.each` fits in alongside them, but that you'll just as often use one of the others because it does what you really want when working through the array. You rarely *just* want to set an iterator.

Comment: @konart I have and I think I understand the differences. This is what I meant by 'variable scoping' in the question. Is this the sole reason it isn't used?

Comment: @Sebastian Carroll consistency as well.

Comment: I use `Enumerable#each` because it's just a method call, not another syntax, and it's more OO.

Comment: I find the `each` more readable, more consistent, and more practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it's uniform syntax. When I am going to do something with array `a`, I just start typing `a.`. What am I going to do? Filter? `a.select`; determine the size? `a.size`. Iterate? `a.each` etc.

Iterating an array is nothing special and requires no special language construct. Also `each`without an immediate block results in an Enumerator, which can be chained with other methods.

Then again, Ruby does have a fine `for i in a` loop. So if you are more comfortable with a for loop: by all means, use a for loop.

Comment: `it is even slightly faster` - I doubt that. Do you have any proof?

Comment: @cremno http://www.monitis.com/blog/2012/02/08/20-ruby-performance-tips/ , nr 11. Does not have to be true however.

Comment: Well, that can't be true as a `for` loop calls `#each`.

Comment: @cremno I can not benchmark a faster for loop, I'll delete the speed remark

Comment: @steenslag Thanks for the illustrative response. I now realise I have been looking at it the wrong way. Now I understand the thought process behind it, I find it much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Because `for` loop is less objective and more limited in use.

From the OOP point of view, possibility of iterating through elements of an object is a property/characteristic of that object. Using explicit "outer" way either with a global function or a keywords find redundant, inconsistent and less objective (encapsulation).

`for` is also more limited, it allows only iterate through object elements. `Enumerator#each` on the other hand allows you much more. You may play with enumerator object like chaining with other methods before values unpacking, passing named blocks, methods converted to procs etc.