# Datatype conversion error in Ruby for-loop

Tags: ruby, for-loop, each, type-conversion

I'm looking for some help understanding why I get an error (no implicit conversion of nil into String) when attempting to use a for-loop to search through an array of letters (and add them to a resulting string, which seems to be the real problem), but not when I use a while-loop or 'each' for the same purposes. I've looked through a lot of documentation, but haven't been able to find an answer as to why this is happening. I understand that I could just use the "each" method and call it a day, but I'd prefer to comprehend the cause as well as the effect (and hopefully avoid this problem in the future).

The following method works as desired: printing "result" which is the original string, only with "!" in place of any vowels.

```
s="helloHELLO"
result=""
vowels=["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
string_array=s.split("")
  string_array.each do |i|
    if vowels.include?(i) 
      result+="!"   
    else 
      result+=i
    end 
  end 
puts result
```

However, my initial attempt (posted below) raises the error mentioned above: "no implicit conversion of nil into String" citing lines 5 and 9.

```
s="helloHELLO"
result=""
vowels=["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
string_array=s.split("")
  for i in 0..string_array.length
    if vowels.include?(string_array[i]) 
      result+= "!"   
    else 
      result+=string_array[i]
    end 
  end 
puts result
```

Through experimentation, I managed to get it working; and I determined--through printing to screen rather than storing in "result"--that the problem occurs during concatenation of the target letter to the string "result". But why is "string_array[i]" (line #9) seen as NIL rather than as a String? I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

If it matters: This is just a kata on CodeWars that lead me to a fundamental question about data types and the mechanics of the for..in loop. This seemed very relevant, but not 100% on the mark for my question: ["for" vs "each" in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294509/for-vs-each-in-ruby).

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:

Okay, I think I figured it out. I'd still love some answers though, to confirm, clarify, or downright refute.

I realized that if I wanted to use the for-loop, I should use the array itself as the "range" rather than "0..array.length", like so:

```
s="helloHELLO"
result=""
vowels=["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
string_array=s.split("")
  for i in string_array
    if vowels.include?(i) 
      result+= "!"   
    else 
      result+=i
    end 
  end 
puts result
```

So, is it that since the "each" method variable (in this case, "i") doesn't exist outside the scope of the main block, its datatype become nil after evaluating whether it's included in the 'vowels' array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got beaten by the classical error when iterating an array starting with index 0, instead of length as end position it should be length-1.
But it seems like you come from some other programming language, your code is not Rubyesque, a 'For' for example is seldom used.
Ruby is a higher language than most others, it has many solutions build in, we call it 'sugared' because Ruby is meant to make us programmers happy. What you try to achieve can be done in just one line.

```
"helloHELLO".scan(/[aeoui]/i).count
```

Some explanation: the literal array "hello HELLO" is a String, meaning an object of the String class and as such has a lot of methods you can use, like scan, which scans the string for the regular expression /[aeoui]/ which means any of the characters enclosed in the [], the i at the end makes it case insentitive so you don't have to add AEOUI. The scan returns an array with the matching characters, an object of the Array class has the method count, which gives us the ... Yeah once you get the drift it's easy, you can string together methods which act upon each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop:

```
for i in 0..string_array.length
```

loops from 0 to 10.

But `string[10] #=> nil` because there is no element at index 10. And then on line 9 you try to add `nil` to `result`

```
result = result + string_array[i] #expanded
```

You can't add `nil` to a string like this, you have to convert `nil` to a string explicitly thus the error. The best way to fix this issue is to change your for loop to:

```
for i in 0..string_array.length-1
```

Then your loop will finish at the last element, `string[9]`.