# Is it possible to write a single-statement for loop in two lines with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, for-loop

Often when programming in Ruby, I find myself writing small **for loops** with a single statement in the body. For example...

```
for number in 1..10
  puts number
end
```

In other languages like `C`, `Java` or `Kotlin` (for example), I'd be able to write the same code in two lines. For example...

```
// Kotlin
for (number in 1..10)
    println(number)
```

In the above example, the ending of the loop body is inferred due to the lack of curly braces.

**Does Ruby have a way to imitate this "single-statement" style of "for loop"?**

Here are some of [my options/your potential replies], along with my thoughts on them.

- > You could append `; end` to the body to end it on the same line.

  This is true, and pretty sufficient, but I'd like to know if there's a more *idiomatic* approach.
- > This seems unnecessarily picky. Why would you ever want to do this?

  You may think I'm being too picky. You may also think what I'm trying to do is un-idiomatic (if that's even a word). I totally understand, but I'd still love to know if it's do-able!

  Doing this could let us write code that's *even just a tiny* bit nicer to read. And for programmers, **readability *matters***.

Comment: The infamous "goto fail" feature.

Comment: @Stefan I think heartbleed had a similar issue with missing curly braces. The last company I worked for required them to be there. I like the shortness of excluding them though, and I do TDD so I'm very unlikely to get caught by an unexpected bug like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you're looking for `each`, [Range#`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Range.html#method-i-each) in this particular case:

```
(1..10).each { |number| puts number }
```

For more complex iterations use `do` - `end` block syntax. For example

```
(1..10).each do |number|
  puts number
  some_method_call(number)
  Rails.logger.info("The #{number} is used")
  something_else
end
```

To find more check out [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org), in particular, see [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html).

Comment: This is quite nice, although I find it a little unusual to read. Will it appear more natural the more I use it?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson Yes it will. The `for` loop really never needs to be used in ruby.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson absolutely. This is the conventional way to iterate over a collection in Ruby

Comment: Perfect & thank you! I'll mark your answer as accepted after 10 minutes (assuming nobody else comes along and writes a better answer) ;)

Comment: After 10 minutes of using this, it actually looks extremely nice.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson yep :) Also, use `{}` for one liner, if you need to do something more complex inside the block, use `do` `end` block, inside of which you can use new line to do new operation while being in the same iteration

Comment: Thanks for a tip. I was aware there was a slight difference between the two kinds of blocks.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: the __real__ idiomatic way to run a counter would be `10.times do`. Or `1.upto(10) do`. No need to involve a range here :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: you can do multiline blocks with `{}`, no problem. In some cases, it's even preferred! There is a difference between `{}` and `do end`, but it's not that. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yea, both points are as usual very good - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an even shorter syntax.

If you are just calling one method on each object you can use `&` syntax.

```
(1..3).collect(&:odd?) # => [true, false, true]
```

This is the same as

```
(1..3).collect { |each| each.odd? } # => [true, false, true]
```

This is the preferred way of writing loops in Ruby.

You'll quickly get used to both `&` and `{}` block syntax and the enumeration methods defined in `Enumerable` module. Some useful methods are

- `each` which evaluates the block for each element
- `collect` which create new array with the result from each block
- `detect` which returns the first element for which block results true
- `select` which create new array with elements for which block results true
- `inject` which applies "folding" operation, eg `sum = (1..10).inject { |a, b| a + b }`

Fun fact, style guides for production code usually ban `for` loops at all because of a subtle but dangerous scoping issue. See more here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41308451/24468

Answer (score 2):

There is a vanishingly tiny number of cases, where any self-respecting Ruby programmer would even write an explicit loop *at all*. The number of cases where that loop is a `for` loop is exactly zero. There is no "more idiomatic" way to write a `for` loop, because `for` loops are non-idiomatic, period.