# Use variable's value in Proc definition

Tags: ruby

How can I use a variable's value at the point of Proc definition instead of defining the Proc with a reference to the variable? Or how else would I approach the problem of defining a list of different steps to be executed in sequence based on an input sequence?

**Example:**

```
arr = []
results = [1,2,3]
for res in results
  arr << Proc.new { |_| res }
end
p arr[0].call(42)
p arr[1].call(3.14)
```

**Expected output:**

```
1
2
```

**Actual output:**

```
3
3
```

Comment: This is a good question because it exposes some interactions between Ruby keywords and scope gates that are non-obvious. I provide a deeper explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why Your Code Doesn't Work as Expected: Shared Closure Scope

By definition, a [Proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html) is a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) that retains its original scope but defers execution until called. Your non-idiomatic code obscures several subtle bugs, including the fact that the [for-in control expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop) doesn't create a scope gate that provides the right context for your closures. All three of your Proc objects share the same scope, where the final assignment to the *res* variable is `3`. As a result of their shared scope, you are correctly getting the same return value when calling any of the Procs stored in your array.

### Fixing Your Closures

You can make your code work with some minor changes. For example:

```
arr = []
results = [1,2,3]
results.map do |res|
  arr << Proc.new { |_| res }
end

p arr[0].call(42)   #=> 1
p arr[1].call(3.14) #=> 2
```

### Potential Refactorings

#### A More Idiomatic Approach

In addition to creating a proper scope gate, a more idiomatic refactoring might look like this:

```
results = [1, 2, 3]

arr = []
results.map { |i| arr << proc { i } }
 
arr.map { |proc_obj| proc_obj.call }
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

#### Additional Refinements

A further refactoring could simplify the example code even further, especially if you don't need to store your inputs in an intermediate or explanatory variable like *results*. Consider:

```
array = [1, 2, 3].map { |i| proc { i } }
array.map &:call
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

#### Validating the Refactoring

Because a Proc doesn't care about arity, this general approach also works when [Proc#call](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html#method-i-call) is passed arbitrary arguments:

```
[42, 3.14, "a", nil].map { |v| arr[0].call(v) }
#=> [1, 1, 1, 1]

[42, 3.14, "a", nil].map { |v| arr[1].call(v) }
#=> [2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: More idiomatic still would be `arr = results.map { |i| proc { i } }` and `arr.map(&:call)`.

Comment: You write that a Proc retains its original scope, but isn't the block passed to `map` (or any block argument) also a Proc? Could the difference in scope creation be the reason why Rubocop suggests using `each` instead of for-in loops?

Comment: @rubystallion There are exceptions to every rule, but the Ruby Style Guide explains why you [generally want to avoid for-loops](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-for-loops). RuboCop more or less implements the style guide, so that's why it recommends using #each and #map to create scope gates that avoid problems like the one you experienced.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `proc` object use the context inside the loop the following should work

```rb
def proc_from_collection(collection)
  procs = []
  collection.each { |item| procs << Proc.new { |_| item } }
  procs
end

results = [1,2,3]

arr = proc_from_collection(results)
p arr[0].call # -> 1

p arr[1].call # -> 2
```

After reading Todd A. Jacobs answer I felt like I was missing something.

Reading some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294509/for-vs-each-in-ruby) on stackoverflow about the `for loop` in ruby made me realize that we do not need a method here.

We can iterate the array using a method that does not pollute the global environment with unnecessary variables like the `for loop` does.

I suggest using a method whenever you need a proper closure that behaves according to a Lexical Scope (The body of a function is evaluated in the environment where the function is defined, not the environment
where the function is called.).

My first answer is still a good first approach but as pointed by Todd A. Jacobs a 'better' way to iterate the array could be enough in this case

```rb
arr = []
results = [1,2,3]
results.each { |item| arr << Proc.new { |_| item } }

p arr[0].call # -> 1

p arr[1].call # -> 2
```